# Error submitting a form with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, submit, greasemonkey

I'm using Greasemonkey to submit a form on an external site. However, I'm running into an issue since the form's submit button is named `submit`.

In firebug, `document.filingform.submit();` is returning the error:

> document.filingform.submit is not a function

Is there a way I can use Greasemonkey to either change the name of the submit button to something other than submit, or to call the `submit()` function of the form successfully?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to show the form's HTML.

Answer (score 1):

It would be something like `document.forms.filingform.submit();`, but don't do it that way!

This approach is liable to be blocked by sandboxing.  Also, some pages require javascript functions to run on a legitimate submit.  The most robust way to submit a page, and keep it and its server happy, is to "click" the submit button.

Code like:

```
var submitBtn   = document.querySelector ("form[name='filingform'] input[name='submit']");
var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');

clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
submitBtn.dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
```

Comment: thanks!  That worked great.  I guess I don't have enough rep to upvote yet, but I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it worked for you.  Please [signal that this question has been answered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).